# Javascript or jquery to check table row value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some javascript code that adds products to a table dynamically.

However, I need s nippet that checks if there already is a row that contains a product to prevent multiple entries of the same product?

I must check the id="Articles_0__ArticleId" and value="2", to see if there are any other Articles_X__ArticleId that is also 2.

X is the row number, 0 based. However, if someone adds 3 products we rows 0,1,2. If you then remove row 1, we end up with 0,2. So it must account for that.

The rows look like this:

```
<tr id="Articles[0]">
<td class="col-md-1">
    <input id="Articles_0__CollectionName" name="Articles[0].CollectionName" value="Articles" type="hidden">
    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Artikelid must be a number." data-val-required="The Artikelid field is required." id="Articles_0__ArticleId" value="2" name="Articles[0].ArticleId" type="hidden">
    <input data-val="true" data-val-length="The field Bild must be a string with a maximum length of 50." data-val-length-max="50" id="Articles_0__ImagePath" name="Articles[0].ImagePath" value="/images/projector.jpg" type="hidden">
    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Namn field is required." id="Articles_0__Name" name="Articles[0].Name" value="Projektor" type="hidden">
    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Pris must be a number." data-val-required="The Pris field is required." id="Articles_0__Price" name="Articles[0].Price" value="60,00" type="hidden">
    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Order Base Id must be a number." data-val-required="The Order Base Id field is required." id="Articles_0__OrderBaseId" name="Articles[0].OrderBaseId" value="2" type="hidden">
    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Totalpris must be a number." id="Articles_0__Total" name="Articles[0].Total" value="" type="hidden">
    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Existing Quantity must be a number." id="Articles_0__ExistingQuantity" name="Articles[0].ExistingQuantity" value="" type="hidden">
    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Passed Production Time field is required." id="Articles_0__PassedProductionTime" name="Articles[0].PassedProductionTime" value="False" type="hidden">

    <input name="Articles.Index" value="0" type="hidden">

    <div class="image-thumbnail-normal">
        <img src="/images/projector.jpg" alt="article image">
    </div>
</td>
<td class="col-md-3">Projektor    </td>

<td class="col-md-1">
    60,00 kr / Styck
</td>
<td class="col-md-1">
    0,00 kr / Styck
</td>
<td class="col-md-1">
    <div class="form-group"><div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-13">
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: If your question concerns javascript, you should include your JS code, not (just) HTML.

Comment: If you had read the questions, you would have know that i don't have the code as I have no idea on how to get started in this scenario.

Comment: In that case, the question is not fit for StackOverflow.

Comment: make your code available online

Comment: @RobertBenedetto you should at least try to do some JS coding first so someone can help you :)

Comment: @RobertBenedetto This is not a site to ask for the code. First, try for yourself and if you're having any difficulties in code then ask questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the input to check is always the second in its td... Something like this?

```
function alreadyExists(myId,myValue) {

    $('tr').each(function() {

        var $myInput = $(this).children('td').first().children('input').eq(1);

        if (($myInput.attr('id') == myId) && ($myInput.val() == myValue))
            return 1; // This id and value already exist
    });

    return 0;
}
```

If you can, I'd put a class to that input, so you can select it independently of its position...

```
var $myInput = $(this).find('input.checkinginput');
```

I hope it helps

Comment: THANK YOU for providing a start snippet for me, just what I needed. A little push in the right direction.

Comment: @A. lglesias you are doing too many nested query to find element which is unnecessary

Comment: @krishnar Yes, I know... but only because I don't like to depend on specific values (maybe they change it in the future). I don't like even depending on the position, and that's why I was proposing him to set a class. Anyway, thank you for the advice! ;)

Comment: @A.Iglesias  if thats the case why big nested query?.  U can just do $(this).find('input.checkinginput'). I hope u got it

Comment: @krishnar You're right! Edited

Comment: @A.Iglesias check my solution its compact.Upvote if my answer found useful.Thank YOu

Comment: Havent been able to check to code yet, will do so tomorrow. WIll upvote if successful :)

Comment: Based on the two examples provided (thanks guys), I came up with this that does the trick:

      $('tr').each(function() {
                    try {
                        var currentArticleValue = $("[name='" + this.id + ".ArticleId']").val();
                        if(currentArticleValue == myValue) {
                            hasArticle = true;
                        }
                    } catch (err) { }
                });
    
                return hasArticle;

Answer (score 0):

```
function already_exists?(new_val) {
    $('tr').each(function() {
        var $element = $(this).find("input[id$='ArticleId']");
        if ($element.val() == new_val)){
            return true;
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks to you too! Short, simple starter snippet was just what I needed. Will use this and the code supplied by Iglesias, and I'll surely make it work. Thanks.

Comment: @RobertBenedetto  please upvote anwer if its usefule

Comment: @RobertBenedetto  i hope u just want to find whether already article_id present or not? I updated solution please check. and upvote if its useful

Comment: Hi, will test this answer as well tomorrow, thanks!